# MVC Required field validation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

Required field validation not firing.

**Model:**

```
public class Client
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Name Required")]
        [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public string Fax { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Client client)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                ClientRepository rep = new ClientRepository();
                rep.AddClient(client);
                rep.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

**View:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Create
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Add New Client</h2>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Fields</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mobile) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Mobile) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telephone) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Telephone) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telephone) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fax) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fax) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fax) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Company) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company) %>
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>

    <div>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: **[Why server side validation and not Client side](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16245682/2007801)**

Comment: @user2007801 Just for the records, you must never trust in user input. Client side validation can be disabled-manipulated-faked, etc, so server side validation is always necessary.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [ModelState.IsValid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410404%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property

```
public ActionResult Create(Client client)
{

  if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
   // TODO: Add code here
      ClientRepository rep = new ClientRepository();
      rep.AddClient(client);
      rep.Save();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   return View(client);
}
```

Comment: I think this is not the answer. This is a other way to validate fields.

Answer (score 0):

For required field validation decorate your function with  `[BindRequired(ErrorMessage = "Name Required")]` instead of using  `[Required(ErrorMessage="Name Required")]`