# Refresh Partial View

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

My view has a partial that I simply pass in a model that is based on an index. So when I click the previous or next button I pass in the correct index.  However I have no idea how to refresh the partial view with the new index.  Every example I find has to do with using a controller but all I want to do is update the index and refresh it that way.

My View --

```
        <div id="partialForm">
        @Html.Partial("_AudienceFaxComposit", Model.AudienceFaxes[start])
    </div>
    <ul class="pager">
        <li><a href="#" id="prev">Prev</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="next">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
```

My script that I have started...

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#next").on("click", function () {
        start = next;
        next = next + 1;
        prev = prev + 1;           
        $.ajax({
            url: '_AudienceFaxComposit'
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: Have You tried something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439128/refresh-partial-view-with-multiple-parameters

Comment: Do I need to use a controller?  Maybe that is what will solve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Yes you will need a controller. As you might have already seen in examples (as mentioned in you post) that a controller is required to process the request which in your case will be an action that returns a partial view with said parameters. HTH

Answer (score 1):

Well in my opinion, You should use @Html.Action not @Html.Partial and yes create a controller action for that, pass parameters to it and return partialview with model.