# Using MVC the button controls click event is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I build a web site with MVC4, and in my `routeConfig` file I have this procedure:

```vb
Public Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}")
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx")
    default.aspx will load instead
    routes.MapRoute(
        name:="Default",
        url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.controler = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    )
End Sub
```

In my `HomeControler` I have this function:

```vb
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Return View("Default")
End Function
```

Thus my `Default.aspx` is working just fine. But.
When I'm trying to `click` a button cannot Handle the `onclick` event (never goes to the sub.
So I use a `OnClientClick` in `aspx` to raise up this event.
But throws me the error of:

> grFlagsBtn_Click' is undefined

And one more issue... I've noticed the program remains on `Home/Index` environment. Where there is no any Index file at this area.
But the Url in my browser says `href="http://localhost:49224/Home/Index"`
I found that very much strange, because the program should be in `/Home/Default`.. I think, I'm not of that.
Please is some one to give me some help on this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure mvc doesn't have server event like onclick it all has to do with the [different route actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440365/how-to-trigger-button-click-in-mvc-4).

Comment: @ the_lotus So will never be able to handle the `onclick` event which is in asp.net ?

Comment: MVC is radically different in it's way of handling postback compared to winform. Even if both have the acronym ASP.NET in them.

Comment: @ the_lotus I choose MVC for better organize and better work. Now.. I don't know

Comment: Don't give up :) MVC has a lot of advantages. A small tutorial should be enough to let you understand how it all works. Just think "In MVC there are no events on controls".

Comment: Probably have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/102558/11683 and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/575397/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-ASP-NET-MVC-for.

Comment: So I think it is an opportunity to work with `Javascript`. And call functions and procedures from this environment. Any Idea ???

Comment: MVC uses helpers to create the HTML code. You can write pure html instead or add the onclick event into the object that runs a javascript to perform a POST/GET. ex: @Html.RadioButton("name", "1", false, new { onclick = "ShowOption(this)", id = p.id })

Comment: You can also create a form and put your controls in it then change the onclick OR onchange for "$("#myForm").submit();"

Comment: @  Chillzy  thank you for your answer. But I decide to approach my issue from another point of view. You see I don't to get reed the ASPX markup page. I have adapted with it very well.  Thank you all any way.

Comment: This Question has it's answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762756/auto-postback-in-mvc4-razor-page]