# Auto postBack in MVC4 razor page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I start to work in a MVC4 environment.
And of course I have many problems. One of these is the use of button click event.
Any instruction I may use, this post back destroys the flow of my program.
Because it executes any instruction I put for other uses.
I use 'Java Script' to handle the `onclick` event like that:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function IntegrityOnClick(status) {
 switch (status) {
 case 1:
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("CheckIntegrity_Click", "Models/_mainPage")',
    dataType: 'json'
    });
 case 0 :
    return;
 default:
 }
}
```

I this case threw me the error of `404 not found`
If I change the `url:` to

```
'@Attributes.codeBehind.CheckIntegrity_Click'
```

Then the `event` works just fine, but it fires with the page load as well, which is not the desired one.
It obvious that somewhere my code isn't so well formed but I don't know where is this mistake.
And the question is: 
Is there a way to run `button click event` on my razor page, in the right way? (without post-back interferes).
I've check all the internet for a solution, but what I found was very complicated, and I can't developed.
Is there any way to assist me on this issue?.
**ADDITION 19/2/19 17:30** 
With the assistance of @Marcelo Vismari I finally end up with the following code
The Button first.

```
 <button id="checkIntegrity" class="checkIntegrity" onclick="IntegrityOnClick()">
```

The Script second.

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
    function IntegrityOnClick() {
    // It'll generate an ajax request to IntegrityBtn_Click action, on controller.
    // It's not refresh your page, so will not destroy your flow.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("IntegrityBtn_Click")',
        dataType: 'json',
                });
}
</script>
```

And the controller site last.

```
Public Function IntegrityBtn_Click() As JsonResult
        Return Json(New With {Key Attributes.codeBehind.CheckIntegrity_Click}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    End Function.<br/>
```

I hope to help anybody has facing the same issues on his code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To control your program flow use some ajax calls with javascript:

```
<input type="button" onclick="myEvent()" />

public class YourController : Controller 
{
    public JsonResult CheckIntegrity_Click() {
        return Json(new { message = "aaa", foo = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
    }
}

<script>
    function myEvent() {
        // It'll generate an ajax request to CheckIntegrity_Click action.
        // Then it'll return some data back.
        // It's not refresh your page, so will not destroy your flow.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckIntegrity_Click")',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                // Here is data returned by CheckIntegrity_Click action
                alert(data.message); // aaa
                console.log(data.foo); // true
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes...  that was a grate solution to my issues with `post back`. Of course with some changes because that I need is to run a sub in a class under the Model sub directory. So I run it directly from my controller. And then the control returns  to my page without any problem.... 
Thanks again for one more time.