# MVCjqGrid. Add date column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, grid, mvcjqgrid

I have a grid:

```
 @(Html.Grid("grid")
      .SetJsonReader(new MvcJqGrid.DataReaders.JsonReader { Id = "Id", RepeatItems = false })
      .SetRequestType(RequestType.Post)
      .AddColumn(new Column("Date").SetWidth(300).SetLabel("Date").)
      .SetUrl(Url.Action("Action", "Controller"))
      .SetRowNum(10)
      .SetHeight(500)
      .SetRowList(new[] { 10, 15, 20, 50 })
      .SetViewRecords(true)
      .SetGridView(true)
      .SetPager("pager")
    )
```

and data for this grid:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Action(GridSettings gridSettings)
{
    var data = new List<DateTime>();
    data.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(s => new
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(s * 4),
    }));
    int totalRecords = data.Count;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gridSettings.SortColumn))
    {
        data = (gridSettings.SortOrder == "asc" ?
            data.AsQueryable().OrderByPropertyName(gridSettings.SortColumn) :
            data.AsQueryable().OrderByPropertyNameDescending(gridSettings.SortColumn)).ToArray();
    }
    data = data.Skip((gridSettings.PageIndex - 1) * gridSettings.PageSize).Take(gridSettings.PageSize).ToArray();

    var jsonData = new
    {
        total = totalRecords / gridSettings.PageSize + 1,
        page = gridSettings.PageIndex,
        records = totalRecords,
        rows = data
    };
    return Json(jsonData);
}
```

So the question how should i work with Dates? if i leave them as DateTime they will display with no format, but with `Date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(s * 4).ToString()`, will NOT sort correct?

Comment: **[Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15463979/2007801)**

Comment: @ewvfwrwwvw, thx, but how can i call this for MVCjqGid?

Comment: You have to call the Action Method **[using JQuery as mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16245682/2007801)** and in success callback  format the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the data after you sorted (I refactored your controller action a little bit to get it to work):

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetData(GridSettings gridSettings)
        {
            var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(s => DateTime.Now.AddHours(s * 4)).ToList();

            var totalRecords = data.Count();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gridSettings.SortColumn))
            {
                data = (gridSettings.SortOrder == "asc" ?
                    data.OrderBy(x=>x) :
                    data.OrderByDescending(x=>x)).ToList();
            }
            data = data.Skip((gridSettings.PageIndex - 1) * gridSettings.PageSize).Take(gridSettings.PageSize).ToList();

            var id = (gridSettings.PageIndex - 1) * gridSettings.PageSize;

            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalRecords / gridSettings.PageSize + 1,
                page = gridSettings.PageIndex,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = data.Select(d=>new
                    {
                        id = ++id,
                        Date = d.ToShortDateString()
                    })
            };
            return Json(jsonData);
        }
```